# KIImagePager arrayWithImages delegate

Tags: ios, xcode

```
- (NSArray ) arrayWithImages:(KIImagePager)pager { 
         return @[ 
         //@"https://files.parsetfss.com/3cebf0c7-ae8f-4072-bb5a-ea8d98a64e87/tfss-2d805863-4caa-4317-aa75-b865759b4c79-Image.jpg",
         //@"https://files.parsetfss.com/3cebf0c7-ae8f-4072-bb5a-ea8d98a64e87/tfss-695d639d-e275-4226-be25-808cbe8f80e2-Image.jpg",
         //@"https://files.parsetfss.com/3cebf0c7-ae8f-4072-bb5a-ea8d98a64e87/tfss-5a4084bb-d5fe-4ce9-a0b6-3813f205acb0-Image.jpg"];
        return imageURLs; 
  }
```

This method doesn't work though I am populating imageURLs with same URLs as in the commented lines. The commented lines work perfectly but I can't use that as I don't know the URLs before hand and hence I need to populate an array and return that.

[EDIT] I am populating my array in viewDidLoad method like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
    [_imageURLs addObject:string1];
    [_imageURLs addObject:string2];
    [_imageURLs addObject:string3];
}
```

where string1...3 are from a database on the network

Comment: May be show the code that's not working? how do you populate your array?

Comment: @Vladimir I have edited the question to show how I am populating the array. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it working with huge support from the KIImagePager's author Marcus Kida. Thanks Marcus. So for anyone who might face a similar problem, here's the solution from Marcus.

1. Return an instance object array like so

   ```
   - (NSARRAY *) arrayWithImages:(KIImagePager)pager {
          return self.imageUrls;
   }
   ```
2. After getting your image urls/strings, reload your KIImagePager like so:

   ```
   self.imageUrls = ...
   [self.myPage reloadData];
   ```

   And that is it.